# Pros and cons of Java Iterable

Tags: java, optimization, coding-style

Java methods accepting and returning `Iterable<T>` types are very common. The problem I see is that the Iterator [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) is so limited, that it either requires one to reconstruct the Iterable into a usable data structure, or forces the users to perform multiple traversals of the Iterable, increase execution time.

Can someone correct me on this? Are Iterables as bad as I think they are? Are there any techniques that one can use to work-around the limitation of Iterables if you are forced to use them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding *accepting* an `Iterable<T>` this is clearly a good thing. It means you can pass it almost any data structure - it only needs to implement the very simple `Iterable<T>` interface. This makes the code easier to reuse.

For returning an `Iterable<T>` one of the advantages is that the implementation of the method can change - perhaps using a more efficient data structure, or by generating the results lazily as they are requested (e.g. streaming them from disk). It is easy to change the implementation without breaking your clients, because they only depend on the `Iterable<T>` interface. If you had exposed a `List<T>` then you can't be sure that your clients will access the data in sequential order.

You are right that if you need to access the results more than once then it would make sense to first copy the data into a different structure. But only you know what specific collection is most useful for your specific situation. Sometimes it could be an `ArrayList`. Other times you might prefer to store the items in a `HashMap`. So you would often have to copy the data into a new data structure anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in [JDK 8](http://jdk8.java.net/) we will see major improvements on the `Iterable` interface.

With the addition of [extension methods](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/Defender%20Methods%20v4.pdf), the interface will provide default implementations and many new functions will be added to provide the equivalent of high-order functions capable of accepting [lambda expressions](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html), also, [lazy evaluation](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html) will be implemented thanks to their iterative nature and not to mention parallelism, so in fashion these days.

Answer (score 1):

Accepting `Iterable< T >` is a great service to your clients.

Returning it is often a disservice to them.  If you don't plan on changing your mind about what collection you use to implement the result, you should be as specific as you can reasonably be.